# Matplotlib change colour of every second element in yaxis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So I have this plot here:
[image: plot]

**What I want to do is to have every second element of yaxis to be coloured for example in blue and the rest in red.**

**Here is the result I want to get**:
[image: desired result]

and here is the code I got:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

result_7_s = amount * s_7_days
result_14_s = amount * s_14_days
result_21_s = amount * s_21_days
result_7_fc = amount * fc_7_days
result_14_fc = amount * fc_14_days
result_21_fc = amount * fc_21_days
final_y = np.array([int(result_7_s), int(result_14_s), 
                    int(result_21_s), int(result_7_fc), 
                    int(result_14_fc), int(result_21_fc)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(num = 'Test')
x = np.array([7, 14, 21])
plt.xticks(ticks = x, labels = x)
plt.yticks(ticks = final_y, labels = final_y)
plt.title(f'Prices for {amount} people')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.bar(x - 0.5, final_y[:3], width=1, color='#444444', label='Standard')
ax.bar(x + 0.5, final_y[3:], width=1, color='#e5ae38', label='First Class')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors = 'blue')  # <-------
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('{x}$')

plt.legend()
plt.savefig('result.png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the tick labels to apply the desired color to each one of them:

```
for n, tick_label in enumerate(ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    tick_label.set_color("red" if n%2 else "blue")
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but a bit not right.
https://ibb.co/vvKXwgG

Comment: This is because your question is misleading. Guimoute's answer does what you asked for, whereas you want to color the labels based on their group membership. I upvoted this answer because it does what was asked for.

Comment: No it didn't do the thing I wanted. My answer which you can find on this page did. 
And My question was not that misleading as I provided everything, that will show you the desired result. The answer here did not lead to it, though it had some kind of solution.

Comment: Then replace `if n % 2` by `if n < 3` but I don't understand why your answer works and not mine. Your answer should result in 3 blue ticks and 3 red ticks, while the expected result in your question clearly shows an alternance of red and blue, hence the modulo operator. Are your y-ticks not sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came with:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    plt.gca().get_yticklabels()[i].set_color('blue')
    
for i in range(3, 6):
    plt.gca().get_yticklabels()[i].set_color('red')
```